# How to use sendmail in Java?

Tags: java, spring, sendmail

Currently my company is using a 3rd Party services to send emails, instead a decision has been taken to use [sendmail](http://www.sendmail.com/). This is web application which is built on Java, Spring, Ibatis. I am new to sendmail and I need to know the following details:

- How to use **sendmail** in Java?
- Is it possible to use **sendmail** through Spring?
- Please point me to any tutorial as I do not found anything related in [sendmail](http://www.sendmail.com/) website.

Comment: Then really you should be contacting support of that 3rd party sendmail provider

Comment: try looking for some classes/methods/docs in the JARs they'd have probably provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendmail implements the SMTP protocol, so any email handling library (e.g. [javamail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) or [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/)) should work.